# What does compiled method in java mean

Tags: java

Please, I often find java methods that are empty with a comment **compiled code**

Here is an example

```
public E get(int index) { /* compiled code */ }
```

I can not find the meaning!! thank you for your clarification

Comment: You often find these? I never have. In what context do you see these?

Comment: my case: using git for collaborative projects

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This often happens when you are using an external library.

It means that your IDE doesn't hold the source code for that library. So he knows the method's name and signature, but not its code